# is is possible to use stunnel / spiped to secure Redis Cluster?

Tags: ssl, redis, stunnel

What is the proper way to ssl secure a Redis cluster? (Client-server, node-node communication).

As mentioned in Redis cluster specification, every node on the cluster listens on 2 ports: the port for "external" communication and another for the cluster bus. 
According to this, each node should have 2 stunnels - accepting on a "fake" port and connecting to "external" \ cluster bus port?

Answer (score 0):

Last week I tried to config a redis server cluster securized with stunnel, and I get to start the cluster with redis-trib, but when the nodes started to send the cluster meet command to the rest of the nodes appears the problems, because the redis library in the nodes said to me that it didn't connect to the nodes. The congirutaion are the same that are specified, with 3 masters and 2 replications nodes for every master, in the stunnel config file define a server that receive information in arbitrary port, securize the ifnormation, and send to redis port in localhost, and a client configuration for every replica node, two in my case, that call to arbitrary port in localhost to the secured port in the external node, and in the redis-trib script specified the secured clients, localhost:xxxx localhost:xxxx ...
I read that the bus port is special, and i didn't try to secure this in the nodes, only the acces port to redis for every node. Any other option to try?